# Python Itrtools and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I have a script which is using itertools cycle, zip_longest to interate through a list and a file.
For example, in the below code json_file_list is the list of files in which, each json_file has meant to process N number of lines from url_list file and keep repeating the operation until all the lines of url_list are processed. Unfortunately this operation is very slow. Is there a way to use multiprocessing here, so that each json file can process N number of lines from url_list file concurrently and the operation keep repeating itself until all lines in url_list are processed.

```
batch_size = 100

JSON_KEY_FILE_PATH = "json_files/"
JSON_FILENAME = '*.json'
json_file_list = glob.glob(JSON_KEY_FILE_PATH + JSON_FILENAME, recursive=True)
itr_length = len(json_file_list)


SCOPES = [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing" ]
ENDPOINT = "https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish"

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def GoogleApiCall(url_file, json_file_list):
    with open(url_file) as f:
        counter = 0
        for json_file, lines in zip(cycle(json_file_list), grouper(f, batch_size)):
            # json_data = json.load(open(json_file))
            credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_file, scopes=SCOPES)
            http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
            counter += 1
            for line in lines:
                content = """{
                    url: "%s",
                    type: "URL_UPDATED"
                }"""%line
                if line:
                    response, content = http.request(ENDPOINT, method="POST", body=content)
                    if(response.status == 200):
                        s1 = str(line)
                        s2 = 'successfully indexed, wait a while for google to refresh'+'\n'
                    else:
                        s1 = str(line)
                        s2 = 'failed to be indexed'+'\n'
                    print ("=========================")
                    print ("====>> " + str(json_file))
                    print(response)
                    
            print ("my counter:" + str(counter))
            if counter % len(json_file_list) == 0:
                time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: You could use threadpools to speed up what you are doing I think. But have you confirmed that the slow down is CPU capped or IO capped? Threading helps with IO. Multiprocessing with CPU caps.

Comment: Any other way to improve the performance here ?

Comment: Improving performance would require looking at where the time is being spent. Have you tried profiling your code to see what takes the most time? Once you find where your code is running 'slow' then you can focus on that section of code for improvement. I would venture that using threadpools on your API requests would speed up your code quite significantly.